# How to carry audio over SSH?

Tags: networking, sound, ssh

Is there a way to carry audio over ssh?

Say after connecting to remote machine through `ssh -X` I opened a browser and want to watch a youtube video. Currently I could only able to watch the video without any audio. But I want to hear the audio too. How to do that?

Comment: I'm just curious: How do you watch a video trough `ssh`?

Comment: @RaduRădeanu he's forwarding the Xserver ;)

Comment: I was saying about youtube video. after connecting I just open a browser and watch youtube there. It works but gives several error messages about pulse audio. I have tried vlc to open .mp4 and .avi files. vlc stops working saying "Audio output failed: The audio device "default" could not be used: Connection refused."

Answer (score 13):

### How to carry audio over SSH?

Stolen answer from [grawity](https://superuser.com/users/1686/grawity) in [SuperUsers](https://superuser.com/a/311830/235569):

> The easy way: Run `paprefs`, go to *Network Server* and check *Enable
> network access to local sound devices*.

You need to install it using

```
sudo apt-get install paprefs
```

> Whenever you SSH with X11 forwarding enabled, PulseAudio programs use
> X11 to discover your sound server (use `pax11publish` or

> ```
> xprop -root PULSE_SERVER
> ```
>
> to see for yourself). Just tell PulseAudio to listen for
> network connections (`paprefs` as described above), and all X11
> programs will be able to use it.
>
> (Other users will not have access to your sound server, unless you
> allow it yourself in `paprefs`. The authentication data is carried
> over in the X11 `PULSE_COOKIE` property, or you can copy
> `~/.config/pulse/cookie` manually.)
>
> Note however, that the PulseAudio stream is not encrypted this way, so
> it is okay for use at home, but not over the Internet.
>
> ---
>
> The slightly more complicated way: Enable network access as above, but
> tunnel PulseAudio over SSH TCP forwarding. Use `pax11publish` to
> discover your PulseAudio port (usually 4713), connect with
>
> ```
> ssh -R 24713:localhost:4713
> ```
>
> then run
>
> ```
> export PULSE_SERVER="tcp:localhost:24713"
> ```
>
> This will be slightly slower due to SSH overhead, but is safe to use
> over the Internet.

Comment: From @Fusca Software: Just a comment to the last answer: First redirecting a Browser with youtube will hardly work over a 1GBit-Connection, so I think I will not use it over a public (Internet) connection. Second, if you watch a youtube (!!!) video, I don't think you should secure the audio stream :D