# audio through ssh/get raw audio from pulseaudio

Tags: server, sound, ssh, pulseaudio, alsa

[How to carry audio over SSH?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/371687/how-to-carry-audio-over-ssh)

was closed with a reference to pulsaudio, which is not what i am asking.

How do I tunnel sound through ssh? I distinctly want a solution using ssh which would work on a headless server. preferably  | ssh user@server " cat | aplay" or something like that, which is possible with aplay itself but not things like vlc or mocp

It is fine and would be nice if i could just select a sink in pulseaudio on my local ubuntu for audio to go into to be able to pipe it around, but pulseaudio on the server is something that i cant rely on doing its job.

Is there a solution or do i have to get a different server setup capable of pulseaudio?

Comment: I don't know where to begin with this but alsa is usually a good replacement or substitute for pulseaudio. Usually alsa and pulse work together but alsa can work alone.